# Remove Duplicates from 2D List (float)

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, floating-point, duplicates

Working on a 3D scanner for my honours project and I know that there'll be overlapping data that could mess up the mesh tessellation. I've got all the points in a 2D array of form `[[x1 y1 z1][x2 y2 z2]...[xn yn zn]]`

If given a 2D list like `[[1.1 1.2 1.3][2.1 2.2 2.3][1.1 1.2 1.3]]` I want to remove duplicates such as the second occurrence of `[1.1 1.2 1.3]`.

If possible I'd like to be able to remove within a certain tolerance (this may make removing floats easier as I hear they're a pain to deal with). This is because I know the data from the different scanner inputs won't give the exact same values. So in pseudo-code:

```
if original + tolerance >= duplicate >= original - tolerance:
    remove
#e.g.
original = [1.1 1.2 1.3] 
duplicate = [1.2 1.2 1.3]
tolerance = 0.1
[1.2 1.3 1.4] >= [1.2 1.2 1.3] >= [1.0 1.1 1.2]
```

Any ideas? Thanks for the help, my brain is fried and I'm still new to programming in general.

Comment: [`itertools.combination`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) might be helpful here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently delete arrays that are close from each other given a threshold in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035503/efficiently-delete-arrays-that-are-close-from-each-other-given-a-threshold-in-py)

Comment: @Georgy Well spotted! I'll take a look over that thread and if it answers my question I'll close the topic :)

Comment: You are trying to identify each pair of triples that are both the result of scanning the same point on a physical object. (In different sessions? While the scanner overlaps scans during on session?) The triples may have different values because the physical scanning is imperfect. First, you should characterize some bound on how much error there can be—how much can each coordinate change between scans? Also establish a bound on how close different points can be—if two different points on the object are scanned, how close can their values be? If the first bound is less than the second bound…

Comment: … then you are done; two triples are scans of the same point if and only if their differences are less than the bound. (Note: If the errors are not the same in each dimension, you might consider bounds for each dimension separately.) However, if the second bound (lower bound on differences of different points) is less than the first bound (upper bound of differences of same point), there can be overlap in the coordinates. In that case, you might consider correlation between the different dimensions. E.g., if the scanning difference is not due to independent errors in each dimension but…

Comment: … is due to some physical motion of the object, then a point that moves significantly in the x dimension will move little in the y dimension—the total physical length of the motion will be under some bound. So you want to compare the sum of the squares of the differences, to compute total length. Again, you need an upper bound for motion of the same point and a lower bound for distances between different points. If the latter is less than the former, the problem appears insoluble. Otherwise, it is a simple matter of programming. So, what are the characteristics of your scanner and its errors?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well reasoned. The scanner is detailed some more here (https://github.com/AcrimoniousMirth/Project-Adam-3D-SCANNER-CODE). Simply put if we have a box with sides *front, back, left* and *right* then cameras are positioned on sides *left* and *right* and laser lines scan along sides *front* and *back*. A photo is taken by each camera for each distance moved and I use OpenCV to extract the laser silhouette in each image, turn it into points, append the Z axis to each point then append those all to an array...

Comment: So then this array is turned into a mesh (I'm thinking by using *scipy convexhull* or *delauney*. I've yet to add lens distortion correction factors and a whole lot more functionality but right now I just need to get a basic program running so I can graduate with a 1st. If you'd like to help please feel free to check and contribute to the GitHub :)

Comment: My area of expertise is in product design engineering, notability with 3d printers, of which I've designed and made a few. Programming is currently a self-taught necessity but it'll be a hobby when I reach the required skill level. I've jumped in the deep end by deciding to see this project through to a working prototype instead of leaving it theoretical but I like its potential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out this is rather similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035503/efficiently-delete-arrays-that-are-close-from-each-other-given-a-threshold-in-py).
Out of curiosity (or more knowledge than me), it would be worth trying the answers posted here.

However I found modifying the first answer to the linked question worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

Removing duplicates is pretty simple using numpy

```
np.unique(x, axis=0)
```

where `x`is your array

Comment: As I'm passing to np anyway that may be best. Any way to do the *within tolerance* part easily with np?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say filter entries that when reduced from other entries, no points pass a certain threshold:

```
def subtract(pts1, pts2):
    # subtract two entries:
    # subtract((1.1, 1.2, 1.3), (1.2, 1.1, 1.3)) = (-0.1, 0.1, 0)
    return tuple(map(operator.sub, zip(pts1, pts2)))

def is_close_enough(match, thresh=0.15):
    return abs(x) <= thresh

def is_close_match(pts1, pts2):
    # check if the match is close enough, create your own THRESH
    distances = subtract(pts1, pts2)
    return all(map(is_close_enough, distances))

def get_duplicates(original, candidates):
    # given an entry and duplicate candidates, return all duplicates
    # candidates.remove(original) # don't match self, not that important
    _is_close_match = lambda candidate: is_close_match(original, candidate)
    return filter(_is_close_match, candidates)
```

To return the unique entries just use `filterfalse`.